# Fastest way to get Inverse Mapping from Values to Indices in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, openmp

Here's a array `A` with length `N`, and its values are between `1` and `N` (no duplication).

I want to get the array `B` which satisfies `B[A[i]]=i` , for i in [1,N]

e.g.

```
for A=[4,2,1,3], I want to get    
B=[3,2,4,1]
```

I've writen a fortran code with openmp as showed below, array `A` is given by other procedure. For `N = 1024^3(~10^9)`, it takes about 40 seconds, and assigning more threads do little help (it takes similar time for OMP_NUM_THREADS=1, 4 or 16). It seens openmp does not work well for very large N. (However it works well for N=10^7)

I wonder if there are other better algorithm to do assignment to `B` or make openmp valid.

the code:

```
subroutine fill_inverse_array(leng, A, B)
use omp_lib
implicit none

integer*4 intent(in) :: leng, i
integer*4 intent(in) :: A(leng)
integer*4 intent(out) :: B(leng)

!$omp parallel do private(i) firstprivate(leng) shared(A, B) 
do i=1,leng
    B(A(i))=i
enddo
!$omp end parallel do

end subroutine
```

Comment: The loop as shown doesn't work. By default, arrays start from index 1. As an aside, the three line explicit loop can be rewritten in one line, by using a vector subscript and an implied do loop, as such: `B(A) = (i, i = 1, leng)`.

Comment: @eriktous Very sorry for that, in my real code A is A(0,leng-1). I forgot to modify it to keep in concordance when post here.

Answer (score 2):

It's a slow day here so I ran some tests. I managed to squeeze out a useful increase in speed by rewriting the expression inside the loop, from `B(A(i))=i` to the equivalent `B(i) = A(A(i))`.  I think this has a positive impact on performance because it is a little more cache-friendly.

I used the following code to test various alternatives:

```
  A = random_permutation(length)

  CALL system_clock(st1)
  B = A(A)
  CALL system_clock(nd1)

  CALL system_clock(st2)
  DO i = 1, length
     B(i) = A(A(i))
  END DO
  CALL system_clock(nd2)

  CALL system_clock(st3)
  !$omp parallel do shared(A,B,length) private(i)
  DO i = 1, length
     B(i) = A(A(i))
  END DO
  !$omp end parallel do
  CALL system_clock(nd3)

  CALL system_clock(st4)
  DO i = 1, length
     B(A(i)) = i
  END DO
  CALL system_clock(nd4)

  CALL system_clock(st5)
  !$omp parallel do shared(A,B,length) private(i)
  DO i = 1, length
     B(A(i)) = i
  END DO
  !$omp end parallel do
  CALL system_clock(nd5)
```

As you can see, there are 5 timed sections in this code.  The first is a simple one-line revision of your original code, to provide a baseline.  This is followed by an unparallelised and then a parallelised version of your loop, rewritten along the lines I outlined above.  Sections 4 and 5 reproduce your original order of operations, first unparallelised, then parallelised.

Over a series of four runs I got the following average times.  In all cases I was using arrays of `10**9` elements and 8 threads.  I tinkered a little and found that using 16 (hyperthreads) gave very little improvement, but that 8 was a definite improvement on fewer.  Some average timings

```
Sec 1: 34.5s
Sec 2: 32.1s
Sec 3:  6.4s
Sec 4: 31.5s
Sec 5:  8.6s
```

Make of those numbers what you will.  As noted above, I suspect that my version is marginally faster than your version because it makes better use of cache.

I'm using Intel Fortran 14.0.1.139 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with 10GB RAM.  I used the '/O2' option for compiler optimisation.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you that your code is more cache-friendly and cache is the bottleneck. However, sorry for my misleading example, `B(i) = A(A(i))` is not allways correct. `B(i) = A(A(i))` is equivelent to `A(A(A(i)))=i i.e. A^3(i)=i` as `B=A^(-1)`. We can try `A=[2,3,4,1]`, it requires `A^4(i)=i`. It deepends on the rotation symmetry of the array, it might take N times to go back for a array with length N.